# Check when a variable has changed in Custom Editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to check whether any variable has changed in a custom Editor Class, but I can't seem to get a result from the check. This is my custom editor class. I am using *EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck()* & *EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck()*:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(TileManager))]
[CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class TileManagerEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        TileManager tileManager = (TileManager)target;

        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();

        serializedObject.Update();

        tileManager.tileCount = (int)Mathf.Clamp(EditorGUILayout.IntField("Tile Count", tileManager.tileCount), 0, Mathf.Infinity);
        tileManager.resizeTileCount = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Resize Tile Count", tileManager.resizeTileCount);
        tileManager.tileSize = EditorGUILayout.Vector3Field("Tile Size", tileManager.tileSize);
        tileManager.tileSpacing = Mathf.Clamp(EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Tile Spacing", tileManager.tileSpacing), 0, Mathf.Infinity);
        tileManager.relativeSpacing = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Relative Spacing", tileManager.relativeSpacing);

        if (tileManager.relativeSpacing == true)
        {
            tileManager.spacingMultiplier = Mathf.Clamp(EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Spacing Multiplier", tileManager.spacingMultiplier), 0, Mathf.Infinity);
        }

        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("tilePrefab"), true);
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("tileHolder"), true);
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("tiles"), true);

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();

        if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
        {
            tileManager.UpdateOnChange();
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried  `Debug.Log(EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())` instead of the if statement, but I don't get an output

Comment: "Change" is not a concept you can check in Progamming. "Difference" is a concept you can check simply. So your goal is to check if there is any difference to a *previous* status. Where do you store the previous status?

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with Unity's documentation to understand the question: https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to track "something has changed" I can think off.

Both I would solve via a custom generic class `changeTrackableValue<T>` (a value where you can track changes). In both case you need a way to decide when all changes have become the "new normal".

**Option 1 - Comparative**

You keep a know "good" value. If the current and the know "good" value do not match, `valueChanged` would return true.

Properties:

- if you take the long route back to the original value, it would read as "unchanged". usually adviseable for a Text Editor
- It would basically double your memory demand, if not more then that (if parts are cut or added wholesale)
- the original value does not need to be a property

**Option 2 - the archive Bit**

I copy that from the Filesystem. You use a property with a custom set for the value. You store one `bool changed = false` with each value. If the value is changed via set function, you set `changed = true`.

Properties:

- minimal increase in memory useage
- any change is tracked, even the ones back to the original state (can be good or bad)
- you need a property with a public set and need to be able to modify said setter.

I can provide code for either one, if you need it.

Comment: @LewisDawson If you know a better answer, write it. Do not complain that other people actually do something to help the poster.